# How to have cron run a python script as root?

Tags: cron, root

How can I get `cron` to run a python script as root? Here is my crontab file:

```
0 * * * * ./twitter/twitter.py
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11):

If that's root's crontab (edited with `sudo crontab -u root -e` or `su -c 'crontab -u root -e'` or similar), then `./twitter/twitter.py` will run every hour. If this is the system crontab (`/etc/crontab`), a sixth field is needed after the asterisks: `0 * * * * root …`. I recommend using the root user's crontab and leaving the system crontab to the system.

`./twitter/twitter.py` starts from the current directory. Cron can't guess what you want the current directory to be: you never told it. Change this to use the absolute path to the script, e.g. `/home/paul/scripts/twitter/twitter.py`.

You'll need to make sure that `twitter.py` starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python` (I'm assuming it is a Python script) and that `python` is in cron's default `PATH` (this will depend on your brand of unix; you can be sure that `/usr/bin` is in the default `PATH`, but if your `python` lives elsewhere such as `/usr/local/bin`, you may need to add a line like `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin` at the top of the crontab).

Also make sure that the script is executable (`chmod +x …/twitter.py`).